# Travelling Sales Man problem

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I am studying the [Travelling Sales Man](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) problem:

> Given a list of cities and the distances between each pair of cities,
>   what is the shortest possible route that visits each city exactly once
>   and returns to the origin city?

And I wonder: given a list of cities/distances that the salesman must visit, is it possible to estimate the solution (shortest path) without finding it? Or is doing a rough estimate about as hard as finding the actual paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are, see [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Heuristic_and_approximation_algorithms). Modern methods can find solutions for extremely large problems (millions of cities) within a reasonable time which are with a high probability just 2–3% away from the optimal solution.